# Using app's name in ng-app won't work; have to use the controller name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller to pick one json file to read depending on user input:

```
var HomeControllers= angular.module('HomeControllers', []);
HomeControllers.controller('HomeLanCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get($lan.concat(".json")).success(function(data) {
    $scope.text = data;
});
});
```

I also have an ng-app that includes this controller:

```
var HomeApp = angular.module('HomeApp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'HomeControllers'
            ]);
```

Eventually, my html looks like:

```
<html lang="en-CA" ng-app="HomeApp">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="HomeLanCtrl">
    <li class="header_list_end"><a href="contactus.html">{{text.id_contactus}}</a></li>
</body>
```

However if this won't work; the {{text.id_contactus}} will be displayed as plain text instead of the actual data in the text object.

But this will work if I change the line

```
ng-app="HomeApp"
```

to

```
ng-app="HomeControllers"
```

in this case the text data will be displayed correctly.

I need a second pair of eyes to dubug... Any comments on why it won't work is highly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space after "HomeApp" in your `angular.module` call.

```
var HomeApp = angular.module('HomeApp ', [
```

should be

```
var HomeApp = angular.module('HomeApp', [
```

If you open your developer console with your current code, you'll see an "uncaught object" exception, which - in this case - indicates that Angular can't find the module you've specified in `ng-app`.

Comment: aha, that space happened when I copied codes over, my real code doesn't have that... besides this space, what else did you find? I also updated the question to remove that space.. sorry about this stupid thing..

Comment: Your sample code ran fine for me once I removed the space, with the exception of the `$http` call, which I removed because I didn't know where you were sending the request to. Now that I'm looking at it, what is `$lan`? It's not injected or declared anywhere.

Comment: hmm, don't see anything else.. thats why I think it's a trick question that worth putting up here... thanks!

Comment: $lan is just a variable for something else not in the sample code. I think removing it won't change anything.

Comment: Nothing else jumps out at me, and the sample code runs fine for me now. Can you post more of the actual code?

Comment: actually I realized that it is something similar(similarly stupid too...). The html imports app.js while the actual file is apps.js . Beat me... For that I will accept yours as answer because that brings my attention to that.. thank you and sorry to take up your time for this!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)